# Is it possible to ask for ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission in hybrid apps?

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to create a new mobile application. This new app will be hybrid and will need to be whitelisted. Nowadays, I have an Android native app that request the permission launching the Intent ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS that let the user the possibility of accept/deny the request.

The permission is needed because it is necessary for my app to send data to a private server even if the mobile enters doze/standby mode.

Is it possible to implement something similar using ionic or react-native (I have not decided yet which hybrid technology I will use and any recommendation is appreciated as well).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes

On android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

On android/app/src/main/java//MainApplication add:

```
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Settings;
```

then on function public void onCreate() before SoLoader.init(); add:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
  myIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
else {
  myIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
  myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
}
getApplicationContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```